# Unable to close dropdown menu when using focus for accessibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to close a dropdown menu once the focus has moved from the dropdown to a regular nav item. I am able to open the dropdown on focus, then focus on all menu items, but when pressing tab to the next parent item. The dropdown menu still shows.

HTML

Regular nav item

```
<li class="nav-item active">
 <a id="regularNavItem" class="nav-link" href="{{ link.url }}" aria-label="{{ link.title }}" tabindex="0">{{ link.title }}</a>
</li>
```

Menu menu item with dropdown

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown has-megamenu">
    <a id="dropdownMenuButton" class="megamenu-item nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="{{ link.url }}" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-label="{{ link.title }}{{ forloop.index }}">
    {{ link.title }}
  </a>
     <div class="dropdown-menu megamenu mt-0 pt-0 pb-0">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="{% if section.settings.featured_product_enable %}col-md-9{% else %}col-md-12{% endif %}">
        <div class="row h-100">
          {% for childlink in link.links %}
            <ul class="child-menu {{ _colClass }} MegaMenu__Item pb-3">
              <div class="dropdown-header">
                <a href="{{ childlink.url }}" class="">{{ childlink.title }}</a>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              {% for sublink in childlink.links %}
                <a href="{{ sublink.url }}{% if sublink.type == 'product_link' %}{% if sublink.object.variants.size > 1 %}?variant={{ sublink.object.variants.first.id }}{% endif %}{% endif %}" aria-label="{{ childlink.title }}{{ forloop.index }}">
                  <li class="dropdown-menu-item">{{ sublink.title }}</li>
                </a>
              {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var x = document.getElementById("dropdownMenuButton");
  var y = document.getElementById("regularNavItem");
  var dropdownMenu = document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu");

  x.addEventListener("focus", onFocus);
  y.addEventListener("focus", onFocus);

  function onFocus() {
    $(".dropdown-menu-item").focus();
    dropdownMenu.classList.add("show-dropdown-menu");
  }

  function focusOff() {
    dropdownMenu.classList.remove("show-dropdown-menu");
  }
});
```

Style

```
.show-dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Comment: Where in your code do you use `focusOff()` function?

Answer (score 0):

try using jquery toggle class, use this inside event

```
$(".dropdown-menu-item").toggleClass("show-dropdown-menu")
```

for the references
[Jquery Toggle Class](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)